# Key of object type in the hadoop mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

New to hadoop and trying to understand the mapreduce wordcount example code from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

The mapper from documentation is -

```
Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
```

I see that in the mapreduce word count example the map code is as follows

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
```

Question - What is the point of this key of type Object? If the input to a mapper is a text document I am assuming the value in would be the chunk of text (64MB or 128MB) that hadoop has partitioned and stored in HDFS.  **More generally, what is the use of this input key Keyin to the map code?**

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

InputFormat describes the input-specification for a Map-Reduce job.By default, hadoop uses `TextInputFormat`, which inherits `FileInputFormat`, to process the input files.

We can also specify the input format to use in the client or driver code:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(SomeInputFormat.class);
```

For the `TextInputFormat`, files are broken into lines. Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text.

In the `public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)` , ***key*** is the line offset and ***value*** is the actual text.

Please look at TextInputFormat API https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html

By default, Key is `LongWritable` type and value is of type `Text` for the `TextInputFormat`.In your example, Object type is specified in the place of `LongWritable` as it is compatible. You can also use `LongWritable` type in the place of `Object`